# Exactly solvable Schrödinger equations on the circle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation, crystals

Are there any (famous?) periodic potential functions in 1d, $V(x) = V(x+L)$, so that the Schrödinger equation with periodic boundary conditions $\psi(x)= \psi(x+L)$ is exactly solvable?

I can do it if $V$ is piecewise constant...

Comment: See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch%27s_theorem

Comment: See the [Kronig-Penney model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_one-dimensional_lattice#Kronig–Penney_model) and the [Mathieu equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_function) (which requires the Mathieu functions)

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/334459/periodic-boundary-condition-for-a-particle-in-a-box

Comment: Note: your question title mentions a circle.  Your question body is not about a circle, it's simply a periodic potential in one dimension.

Comment: Help Ukraine, I had in mind that the wavefunction should also be periodic (psi(x) = psi(x+L)), which I view as equivalent to being defined on a circle.

Thank you The Tiler, LPZ, hft. Mathieu functions are reasonably satisfying answer! Bloch's theorem is new to me, but seems to be trivial if psi (and not merely V) is required to be periodic.